# Is there any way to find the summary of a vector in R without using any inbuilt function or any kind of loop..just operations between vectors?

Tags: r, sum

```
x<-rnorm(100)
```

i want to find the summary of x for example without using inbuilt functions like `sum()` 
or any kind of loops like (for,while,repeat...) 
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: like using fold? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lambda.tools/versions/1.0.9/topics/fold

Comment: What do you mean?

You want the output to be what?

Somenthing like summary(x) outputs?

Comment: What is the point of this - reinventing the wheel? Can you provide a use-case?

Comment: Ah. You wanted the **sum** of `x`, not the **summary**.

Comment: yes..that was my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself..Tthank you all for your replies..

x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rep(1,length(x))
t(x)%*%y

Comment: I don't understand... in your question, you say *"without using inbuilt functions"*, but in your answer you use several inbuilt functions, `rep`, `length`, `t`, and `%*%` are all inbuilt functions.

Comment: I'm sorry i couldn't make myself clear.."without using inbuilt functions" i meant without sum() or any kind of loop specific.I was wondering if i could find the sum of x just with operations between vectors..